# Method does not return start of the list

Tags: python, memory, data-structures, singly-linked-list

So When I run this code it does not work and I found that I have and issue in my `createNewList` method. In this method I am extracting each digit from a number starting from the rightmost digit. I am then adding each of these digits one at a time to a new singly linked list. The issue I have is I am losing reference to the start of the list. At the end of this method I am trying to return the start of the list.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        l1Number = self.listToNumber(self.reverse(l1))
        l2Number = self.listToNumber(self.reverse(l2))
        l1Andl2Sum = l1Number + l2Number
        
        return self.createNewList(l1Andl2Sum)
    
    def createNewList(self, number: int) -> ListNode:
        newList, head = None, None
        
        while number > 0:
            if newList is None:
                newList = ListNode(number % 10)
                head = newList
            else:
                newList = ListNode(number % 10)
            
            newList = newList.next
            number //= 10
            
        return head
            
    
    def reverse(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        previous = None
        
        while head is not None:
            nextNode = head.next
            head.next = previous
            previous = head
            head = nextNode
        
        return previous
        
    def listToNumber(self, head: ListNode) -> int:
        number = 0
        
        while head is not None:
            number += head.val
            head = head.next
            
            if head is not None:
                number *= 10
        
        return number
```

Comment: You don't show us `ListNode`, but my guess is that a new `ListNode` has `next` set to None.  Thus, the loop in `createNewList` will ALWAYS take the `if newList is None:` path.  You shouldn't advance `newList` until you need to add a new node to it.

Comment: Oh lord. I missed that it is always going to my if statement. Thanks for pointing that out.